# Will updating only changed fields help to delay SSD wear out?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, solid-state-drive

I'm updating records of various entities in a database and am actively considering whether it makes sense to create tailored UPDATE requests to prolong SSD life.

Say, if I have an object with 20 properties and a table with corresponding columns for it.

Will it make any difference in amount of bytes written (sectors rewritten) if I execute, say, instead of

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
  Filed1 = @Value1,
  Filed2 = @Value2,
  Filed3 = @Value3,
  .....
  Filed18 = @Value18,
  Filed19 = @Value19,
  Filed20 = @Value20
WHERE
  ID = @ID
```

only

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
  Filed3 = @Value3,
  Filed17 = @Value17,
  Filed20 = @Value20
WHERE
  ID = @ID
```

if only values 3, 17 and 20 were changed?

Will it have any benefit?

Comment: Jeepers hardware is cheap - don't try and optimise your queries to save hardware

Comment: FYI tables have columns not fields

Comment: @Dale K: but you understood what I meant, right? :) sapienti sat

Comment: That's not a good reason to be unclear in ones communication, and even then you spelt field wrong

Comment: Ok, I promise to use exact words

Comment: I think sql server already optimizes and don't updates values that haven't changed in later versions, but it's probably good to avoid updating unchanged fields because it has to bring a lot less data when fetching the above rows *if* your code allows for easy way of doing that. But if you have to write a lot of dynamic sql and stuff, i would say it's not worth it. Also, you're probably supposed to use some kind of SAN and not customer grade SSDs (or *shudder* the cloud)

Comment: When you update all 20 columns instead of 3 SQL Server does not know if the values were actually changed so it creates execution plan that will include ALL of your indexes on that table and this is bad, not only you'll READ unnecessary data but you increase deadlock probability with other data modifications that don't touch all of the indexes. So the problem here is reading, not writing, SQL Server optimizes update and logs and updates only what was really changed

Comment: But then, there's also the fact that one seldom does byte-wise writing, but rather page, so even when updating a couple of fields, it might actually write the whole 4k or 8k pages nullifying some of the above, but at least there's a chance

Answer (score 1):

It will make a difference, but not in the way you think. It will primarily affect *reads* not *writes*. And SSDs are not really affected by large amounts of reads.

SQL Server already optimizes for "non-updating" updates, by reading the value from the existing row, and only updating where it needs to. If nothing on the row changed, (and you weren't using RCSI isolation, and there is no `rowversion` or `GENERATED ALWAYS` columns) then the row isn't updated at all.

But all updates write whole pages, and a row cannot be more than one page, so either way you are writing a whole page. The only time this wouldn't happen is when you have an LOB `max` type, which stores its data off-row if it's too large.

So the write almost always happens, but there is also the read to take into account, because SQL Server wants to know if the value has changed. It requires it to use an index which actually has those columns, which may detrimentally affect the execution plan.

So, if you *know* you aren't changing those columns, don't add them to the `UPDATE`. Otherwise I wouldn't worry about it, as it's already mostly optimized.